# passing variable from controller to view with CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, controller

I'm trying to structure my controllers in several small functions and I'm struggling with the following code:

building controller:

```
public function index(){
   $data['title'] = 'my title part 1';
   $data['title'] .= 'my title part 2';
   $data = $this->function1();
   $data = $this->function2();
   $data['end'] .= 'end of this block';
   $data['main_content'] = 'buildingView';
   $this->load->view('templates/default',$data); 
}

public function1(){
        $data['block1'] = 'test1';
        $data['blockA'] = 'testA';
        $data['blockB'] = 'testB';
        $data['blockC'] = 'testC';
        return $data;
}

public function2(){
        $data['block2'] = 'test2';
        $data['block3'] = 'test3';
        $data['block4'] = 'test4';
        $data['block5'] = 'test5';
        return $data;
}
```

buildingView

```
echo $title;
echo $block1;
echo $block2;
echo $end;
```

The problem is that the `$data` variable from function2 overwrites the one from from function1.
How can I pass the data generated from within Index and both functions?

I've tried the code below but it doesn't work either:

```
$data[] = $this->function1();
$data[] = $this->function2();
```

EDIT: I edited functions 1 & 2 because they actually return an array of several variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding $data variable. So for your condition use `array_merge()` and keep it on top in `$data` variable. Like below

```
public function index(){
   $data1 = $this->function1();
   $data2 = $this->function2();
   $data = array_merge($data1,$data2);
   $data['title'] = 'my title part 1';
   $data['title2'] .= 'my title part 2';
   $data['end'] .= 'end of this block';
   $data['main_content'] = 'buildingView';
   $this->load->view('templates/default',$data); 
}

public function1(){
        $data['block1'] = 'test1';
        $data['blockA'] = 'testA';
        $data['blockB'] = 'testB';
        $data['blockC'] = 'testC';
        return $data;
}

public function2(){
        $data['block2'] = 'test2';
        $data['block3'] = 'test3';
        $data['block4'] = 'test4';
        $data['block5'] = 'test5';
        return $data;
}
```

Comment: easiest solution! easy to implement

Comment: i  have read detailed guide about how to pass value from controller to view in codigniter  http://www.cloudways.com/blog/how-to-pass-data-in-codeigniter/

Answer (score 1):

```
public function index()
{
  $data['title'] = 'my title part 1';
  $data['title'] .= 'my title part 2';
  $data['block1'] = $this->function1();
  $data['block2'] = $this->function2();
  $data['end'] .= 'end of this block';
  $data['main_content'] = 'buildingView';
  $this->load->view('templates/default',$data); 
}
```

The results of your functions will be accessed in the view with the vars `$block1` and `$block2`.

These definitions work better for demonstration purposes

```
public function function1()
{
    return 'test1';
}

public function function2()
{
    return 'test2';
}
```

With the helper function defined as in your question's code

```
public function function1(){
    $data['block1'] = 'test1';
    return $data;
}
```

And assigning the return to a var that is then passed to the view

```
$data['func1'] = $this->function1();
$this->load->view('templates/default',$data);
```

In the view do this to show the result

```
echo $func1['block1'];
```

It is very common and perfectly acceptable to pass arrays to views.

public function function2(){
        $data['block1'] = 'test2';
        $data['block2'] = 'test3';
        $data['block3'] = 'test4';
        $data['block4'] = 'test5';
        return $data;
}

Passed to the view

```
$data['func2'] = $this->function2();
$this->load->view('templates/default',$data);
```

Accessed in the view. This time using an iterator to display each item
in the array.

```
foreach($func2 as $item)
{
   echo $item."<br>";
}
```

Or get each item one at a time

```
echo $func2['block1']."<br>";
echo $func2['block2']."<br>";
echo $func2['block3']."<br>";
echo $func2['block4']."<br>";
```

You can pass object instances to a view too. This version of `function2()` returns an object instance.

```
  public function function2()
  {
    $data = new stdClass();
    $data->block1 = 'test2';
    $data->block2 = 'test3';
    $data->block3 = 'test4';
    $data->block4 = 'test5';
    return $data;
  }
```

Assign the function return to an array that's passed to a view

```
$data['obj2'] = $this->function2(); 
$this->load->view('templates/default',$data);
```

Using it in the view

```
echo $obj2->block1;
echo $obj2->block2;
...
```

Iterators (`foreach`) works on object instances too.

Comment: that's good and I thought of that, however my 2 functions return an array of many variables. Is there a better way to do it? I edited my question

Comment: Passing back an array with many variables is fine - very common practice. No _better_ way comes to mind. As an alternative you can use class objects. I've revised the answer to illustrate using classes.